# Moment.js not displaying all dates correctly

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I'm trying to display the next upcoming Thursdays using Moment.js and not sure why the middle dates are skipping. For example: instead of display: Sep 3, 10, 17, 24, Oct 1

it instead displays Sep 3, 10, 24, Oct 15, Nov 12, Dec 17, etc...

Here's what I have so far:

```
var date = moment();
var y = 3;
while (y<56) {
   var nextThursday = date.weekday(y).add(1,"days").format("dddd, MMM Do");
   var addValueThursday = nextThursday;
   var thurs = {"text": addValueThursday};
   console.log(addValueThursday);
   y+=7;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would find the next 10 occurrences of Thursday, starting this week:

```
   var thursday = moment().startOf('week').add(4, 'days');

   for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
     console.log(thursday.format("dddd, MMM Do"));
     thursday = thursday.add(1, 'week');
   }
```

This would `console.log` something like:

```
Thursday, Sep 3rd
Thursday, Sep 10th
Thursday, Sep 17th
Thursday, Sep 24th
Thursday, Oct 1st
Thursday, Oct 8th
Thursday, Oct 15th
Thursday, Oct 22nd
Thursday, Oct 29th
Thursday, Nov 5th
```

jsbin: https://jsbin.com/gojetisawu/1/edit?html,output

Comment: This seems smarter. You can skip the assignment part in `thursday = thursday.add(1, 'week');` and just do `thursday.add(1, 'week');` as the method mutates the object it's called on.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the answer can be found in what the add function does: *Mutates the original moment by adding time*

So you keep on incrementing an already incremented (through mutation) date.

One solution would be to reset the date inside the loop:

```
var y = 3;
while (y<56) {
    var date = moment();
    var nextThursday = date.weekday(y).add(1,"days").format("dddd, MMM Do");
    var addValueThursday = nextThursday;
    var thurs = {"text": addValueThursday};
    console.log(addValueThursday);
    y+=7;
}
```

This gives an output of:

```
Thursday, Sep 3rd
Thursday, Sep 10th
Thursday, Sep 17th
Thursday, Sep 24th
Thursday, Oct 1st
Thursday, Oct 8th
Thursday, Oct 15th
Thursday, Oct 22nd
```

There might be smarter ways to do this, but I'm not that familiar with the moment library.